# Impossible to save product_id key in has_and_belongs_to_many table ? Key is auto-incremeting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm getting confused with the creation of a new link in a has_and_belongs_to_many table.

I think my use of the .build(...) is not correct but I can't find a way to fix it.

I wrote :

```
@user = User.find(1)
if (params[:product_id])
  @user.products.build(params[:product_id])
end
logger.debug "product id is  #{params[:product_id]}"

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
        ...
```

And the saved relationship in my table products_users is auto-incrementing ???
Example of the content of my table : (user_id ; product_id) = { (1;16) (1;17) (1;18) ...}

And it create blanck lines in the products table with these new id ... ? Is it a cause of build ?

But in the logger, I saw the correct value of :params[:product_id]... so what did I forgot ? :-s

The model is :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
@user.products.build(params[:product_id])
```

try

```
@user.product_ids << params[:product_id]
```

I think that may do the trick for you.

Comment: I did indeed something comparable. Here is what worked for me :@user = User.find(1)                               
    if (params[:product_id])
   @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
   unless @user.products.include?(@product)
    @user.products << @product                           
   end
  end

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me

```
@user = User.find(1)                                                                                                                        
if (params[:product_id])
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  unless @user.products.include?(@product)
    @user.products << @product                                                                                                      
  end
end
```

Comment: That looks like more code than you need; you don't have to instantiate @product here.  Maybe try something like @user.product_ids << params[:product_id] unless @user.product_ids.include?(params[:product_id])